# Some functions are not working after reloading page in rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, reload

I have a navigation bar and sidebar. In the navigation bar, I have a search box, sidebar minimize button, dropdown box for profile, and logout.

In the side bar I have home, about, orders,and contact us.

My rot page is home. Upon loading the root page, some images are not displaying. It displays after clicking the home link in the side bar. The same thing happens for the drop down list, and is also not working after reloading the page. I am also using jquery plugins.

```
//= require jquery  
//= require jquery_ujs  
//= require turbolinks  
//= require_tree .
```

Please help me with what code I need to add to solve my problem. I am new to rails, thanks.
**Update**

```
<div class="table-responsive">
                            <table class="table table-actions-bar m-b-0">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th></th>
                                        <th>product Name</th>
                                        <th>product status</th>
                                        <th style="min-width: 80px;">Manage</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <% i =0 %>
                                    <% @products.each do |products| %>
                                    <% if i == 0 %>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><span data-plugin="peity-bar" data-colors="#5fbeaa,#5fbeaa" data-width="80" data-height="30">5,3,9,6,5,9,7,3,5,2</span></td>
                                        <td><img src="assets/products/iphone.jpg" class="thumb-sm pull-left m-r-10" alt=""> <%= product['productname'] %> </td>
                                        <% if product['status'] != "buy" %>
                                        <td><span class="text-custom"><%= product['status'] %></span></td>
                                        <% else %>
                                        <td><span class="text-danger"><%= produt['status'] %></span></td>
                                        <% end %>
                                        <td>
                                          <a href="#" class="table-action-btn"><i class="md md-edit"></i></a>
                                          <a href="#" class="table-action-btn"><i class="md md-close"></i></a>
                                      </td>
                                  </tr>
```

this is for graph according to data..

Comment: remove `turbolinks` it will solve your issue

Comment: it shows error when remove //= require turbolinks "Sprockets::FileNotFound in product#index couldn't find file 'turbolinks' with type 'application/javascript'"

Comment: did you restart server?

Comment: restarted my server, and some other jquery buttons not working..

Comment: did you able to see your js  file within webpage source

Comment: loading all jquery and js files in every reload page but not working, it works only when we click a any link in the page.. if  we click link first time, only one (jquery) button works other buttons not working, clicking second time the same link, 2 (jquery) buttons works.

Comment: hi, please vote my question.. my account was locked due to no votes.. please vote my question give plus vote uzaif please..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using the jquery.turbolinks gem first?

[jQuery-turbolinks](https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks)

It's tailored to Turbolinks 3 or lower, but you can download the Turbolinks 5 shim and put that in your  if you've already made the jump to 5.

[Turbolinks compatibility shim](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks/blob/master/src/turbolinks/compatibility.coffee)

Comment: this is my gems:- gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely happening because you haven't wrapped your js scripts in a $(document).ready call. You can add turbolinks back to your application.js file and then wrap all of your js scripts in a page:load call as follows:

```
var ready;
ready = function() {

  ...your javascript goes here...

};

$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on('page:load', ready);
```

The page:load will fire when only part of your app is fetched due to turbolinks.

If you have **RAILS 5** you can do:

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {

  ...your javascript goes here...

});
```

Comment: actually i am using jquery plugins like jquery-peity, jquery-chat... how add ready to these files?

Comment: Post the place in your view you're calling these libraries and i'll show you.